# Can I get a count of shared friends and shared groups from the Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way of getting the number of shared friends between a user who's authorised my app and their friends who haven't authorised my app? I just want the count, not a list of those friends.

Same for shared groups?

I've managed to get a list of "taggable" friends, which includes the name of the friend and an obfuscated ID, but there's not really much you seem to be able to do with this.

Comment: "there's not really much you seem to be able to do with this" That's correct, and it's a deliberate choice by Facebook. They have, over the years, moved more and more to limit the amount of data you can get about a user's friends, as those friends never consented to their info going to your app.

Comment: taggable_friends is for tagging only, don´t use it for anything else. what you are trying to achieve is not possible.

Comment: I've changed what I'm doing slightly now. Both users have to be authorised on the app and this makes things much more useful. I can use the user.context all_mutual_friends to get what I need. The only thing I can't do now is get a list of all the groups my user is a part of. I can only get a list of all groups they administer.

Comment: That's another deliberate choice. Groups got locked way down due to spam.